# ionic 3 Error after adding data to firebase

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Just tried making a Training plans page where the user can add his own plans .
tried using firebase but it doesnt work really well..
After I made my first plan and enter the contirbutes of name and the exercise type (Muscle) it just threw me out and showed me that :
I  get this ERROR:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (Plans.html:17)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14376)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13512)
at callViewAction (core.js:13857)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:13815)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
at callViewAction (core.js:13857)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13789)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13513)
at callViewAction (core.js:13857)
```

here is the code by parts:

Plans.ts who supposed to the the data from the firebase and show it on the screen:

```
import { Plan } from './../../models/plan/plan.model';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/ionic-page';
import { PlansListService } from './../../services/plans/plans-list.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-plans',
  templateUrl: 'plans.html'
})
export class Plans {

  planslist$: Observable<Plan[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  private plans: PlansListService) {
    this.planslist$ = this.plans
    .getPlansList()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .map(
      changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key, 
          ...c.payload.val()
        }))
      }
   )
  }


}
```

Here is the Plans.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar >
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Training plans</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Your Plans
    </ion-list-header>
    <div ion-item *ngFor="let plan of planslist$ | async">{{Plan.name}}    </div>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-fab color="fab" bottom right class="fabPalcement">
    <button ion-fab color="fab" navPush='AddPlan'>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>

  </ion-fab>

</ion-content>
```

addplan.ts that supposed to take the data to the firebase by attaching the name and muscles to the 
'name' and 'muscles' variables that I made on the model:

```
import { PlansListService } from './../../services/plans/plans-list.service';
import { Plan } from './../../models/plan/plan.model';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-addplan',
  templateUrl: 'addplan.html',
})
export class AddPlan {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  private plans: PlansListService) {
  }

  Plan: Plan = {

    name: ' ',
    muscles: ' ',
  }


  addNewPlan(plan: Plan){
    this.plans.addNewPlan(plan).then(ref => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('Plans', {key : ref.key})
    })
  }
}
```

addplan.html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>הוסף תוכנית אימונים</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding dir = "rtl">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>שם התוכנית</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="Plan.name" placeholder="התוכנית שלי" item-end></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>קבוצת שרירים</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Plan.muscles">
        <ion-option value="c">חזה</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

<button ion-button (click)="addNewPlan(Plan)">הוסף</button>

 </ion-content>
```

What can I do? where is the problem?? :(

Comment: Please include a [mcve], with emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: Sorry mate, got nothing to delete.. everything I need to show is in there so I can't delete this such things..

Comment: In `Plans.html` you do `*ngFor="let plan of planslist$ | async"` but then you try to interpolate `{{Plan.name}}`. It should be `{{plan.name}}`. JavaScript and TypeScript are case sensitive.

Comment: @Dmitry OMG How the hell did I missed that?!?!?!
Thank you man!
Why is it plan and not Plan? the  Plan.name is not connectd to the variable on the TS file? (It's Plan there)

Comment: `Plans.html` is a template for `Plans.ts`, you don't have `Plan` in `Plans.ts`.